# How do I use serverMiddleware to add dynamic routes to Nuxt sitemap?

Tags: nuxt.js

I have a functioning Express API inside the `/serverMiddleware` directory of my Nuxt SSR app. It has an endpoint `/routes` that returns an array of all the routes I want to add to my sitemap. I also does a `console.log("Backend online")` to know when it completed building and is running.

I'm trying to query my API with the `@nuxtjs/sitemap` module to add those routes to my sitemap but I don't know how to do that. My current approach is this:

```js
// nuxt.config.js

import axios from "axios"

export default {
  modules: [
    "@nuxtjs/sitemap"
  ],

  serverMiddleware: [
    { path: "/api", handler: "./serverMiddleware/index" }
  ],

  sitemap: {
    async routes () {
      const data = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/routes")
        .then(r => r.data)
        .catch(e => console.error("Sitemap error:", e.response))
      return data
    }
  }
}
```

When I run `nuxt start` I get the following output:

```
> nuxt start


   ╭─────────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                         │
   │   Nuxt @ v2.15.8                        │
   │                                         │
   │   ▸ Environment: production             │
   │   ▸ Rendering:   server-side            │
   │   ▸ Target:      server                 │
   │                                         │
   │   Memory usage: 53.2 MB (RSS: 112 MB)   │
   │                                         │
   │   Listening: http://localhost:3000/     │
   │                                         │
   ╰─────────────────────────────────────────╯


 ERROR  Sitemap error: {
  status: 404,
  statusText: 'Not Found',
  headers: {
    'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
    'accept-ranges': 'none',
    'content-length': '26942',
    vary: 'Accept-Encoding',
    date: 'Wed, 26 Jan 2022 21:25:02 GMT',
    connection: 'close'
  },
  config: {
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/routes',
    method: 'get',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'User-Agent': 'axios/0.21.4'
    },
  ...
 }

Backend online
```

Since the `Backend online` message is printed after the 404 error I think the serverMiddleware is only starting after the sitemap tried to call it. This is further proven by the fact that when I open the exact same URL from the axios request in the browser (`http://localhost:3000/api/routes`) I get the correct data array from the API and not a 404.

So I think my question is how can I make the sitemap route function wait until serverMiddleware is running so I can query it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot that way, because the sitemap module have to generate its routes before the Nuxt app initialization.

By design, you have to init your routes directly from an embedded function in your `nuxt.config.js` file. That function can use the same code as your middleware.

As alternative, you can try using the `filter` option as follows:

```
sitemap: {
  async filter ({ routes }) {

    const data = await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/routes")
      .then(r => r.data)
      .catch(e => console.error("Sitemap error:", e.response))

    routes.push(...routes)
  }
}
```

see more about filter https://sitemap.nuxtjs.org/usage/sitemap-options#filter-optional---function